# longest path in directed acyclic unweighted graph in linear time

Tags: graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

how can I find in linear time the longest path in a graph like this one:

3 -> 2

4 -> 3

2 -> 5

I know that the longest path here is 4 -> 3 -> 2 So it has 3 veticles but i dont know how to find it in O(N) time. Please help.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ. This seems off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Top sort the graph and pick vertices in topologically sorted order.

```
For each vertex u
    For each edge (u,v)
       if(d[v] < d[u] + weight(u,v))
          d[v] = d[u] + weight(u,v)
```

Where, d[u] for any vertex u, is the longest distance from the source. For each vertex u, d[u] is initialized to minimum value and d[source]=0.

Since it is a DAG hence we ned to traverse and relax each edge only once. It's basically simplified Bellman Ford algorithm for longest path instead.